# WordPress publish_post hook not firing for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, custom-post-type

I'm currently doing some work with the WP Job Board Manager plugin and I'm wanting to create a function that will fire when a new job is published.

The first thing I did was to create the general hook to find out what the post type was:

```
function newJobAdded() {
    $posttype = get_post_type( $post );
    mail('email@email.com','new job published',$posttype);


 }
add_action( 'publish_post', 'newJobAdded' );
```

Which sent me an email telling me that the post type was: **job_listing**.
I then created a new function that would only fire if the custom post type was **job_listing**

```
function newJobAdded() {

   $posttype = "job_listing";

   if ($post->post_type == $posttype) {
    mail('email@email.com','new job published','done new job publish');
   }


 }
add_action( 'publish_post', 'newJobAdded' );
```

However, nothing happens when I do this. Am I missing something simplistic and noobish?

Comment: Vidya LB has the best answer because you can restrict the hook by the action and type (publishing a job posting => `'publish_job_posting'`).  I just wanted to chime in to say that your second hook doesn't work because you did not pass the `$post` variable in your function which should have been done in the `add_action` call.  When you called `get_post_type( $post );` in your first function, `$post` was actually null.  It only worked because you were already on the post that you were looking for.

Comment: @JasonRoman you have more flexibility with `transition_post_status`. In my method, the function only executes on new posts being published and when the post type is of the selected type

Comment: I don't think that's necessary though - `publish_job_posting` would be triggered whenever a new job_posting is published or has its status changed to publish.

Answer (score 13):

The 'publish_post' action is post type specific. So if you have a custom post type, you need to change the hook you use. if your post type is `job_listing`, the hook you should use is `publish_job_listing`.

```
function newJobAdded($ID, $post ) {
    mail('email@email.com','new job published','done new job publish');
 }
add_action( 'publish_job_listing', 'newJobAdded', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Can you tell me what the '10, 2' is for?

Comment: that  '10, 2'  is for priority and number of arguments respectively, check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Comment: Hey, this works great. It does however also fire when the user saves a job_listing already there. Can I change this to only fire upon initial publish? Much appreciated.

Comment: try adding a conditional statement like if( ( $post['post_status'] == 'publish' ) && ( $_POST['original_post_status'] != 'publish' ) )

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
function newJobAdded($ID, $post) {

}
```

instead of

```
function newJobAdded() {

}
```

Reference: [`publish_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post)

Answer (score 0):

A more general hook will be `transition_post_status` which fires everytime a post's status is changed. You can use `$old_status` and `$new_status` to check the previous and new status of a post then do something.

For a new post, you can something like this: (*Requires PHP 5.3+*)

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{

    if( 'publish' == $new_status && 'publish' != $old_status && $post->post_type == 'my_post_type' ) {

        //DO SOMETHING IF NEW POST IN POST TYPE IS PUBLISHED

    }
}, 10, 3 );
```

**EDIT**

For older versions, use

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'so27613167_new_post_status', 10, 3 );
function so27613167_new_post_status( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{

    if( 'publish' == $new_status && 'publish' != $old_status && $post->post_type == 'my_post_type' ) {

        //DO SOMETHING IF NEW POST IN POST TYPE IS PUBLISHED

    }
}
```

Comment: This gives: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Comment: Then you are using a PHP version older than 5.3. See my update