# Add tag to post type if it is within 3 months of current date

Tags: php, wordpress

I have post types called **articles** and I want to add a tag to the post, if it was published -100 days of the current date.

This is so I can filter these and showcase the most recent posts, and the user can filter the tag on the posts to see **recently added posts** (this is posts -100 days of the current date).

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    ?>
    Found <?php echo $query->found_posts; ?> Results<br />
    <div class='search-filter-results-list'>

        <?php
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

            // Get post published date
            $post_date = get_the_date('Ymd');
            $current_date = current_time('Ymd');
            $future_date = date('Ymd', strtotime('-100 days'));

            // Check if post published date is -100 days before the current date
            $class_to_add = ($post_date <= $current_date && $post_date >= $future_date) ? ' your-custom-class' : '';
            ?>

            <div class='search-filter-result-item<?php echo esc_attr($class_to_add); ?>'>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p><br /><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                    <p><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'small' ); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <p><?php the_category(); ?></p>
                <p><?php the_tags(); ?></p>
                <p><small><?php the_date(); ?></small></p>
                <hr />
            </div>

            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: For a custom post type, you would first of all need to change the hook name, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614748/1427878 But this would only fire when you _publish_ a new post, so what good is this going to do for what you want to achieve here? How is this tag supposed to get _removed_ again, when the three months have passed since its publishing date?

Comment: Yes that's correct. We would also like this added to existing posts too, is that possible?

Comment: Instead of binding this to any particular hook, it would probably make more sense, if you set this up to run once a day, via the WP Cron functionality. Write your own query that fetches all those `articles` posts, loop over them, and update their tags.

Comment: _"This is so I can filter these and showcase the most recent posts, and the user can filter the tag on the posts to see recently added posts"_ - that should not necessarily require setting such a tag in the first place; you can select posts by their publishing date using WP_Query. So this might perhaps be more a case in which you should modify those parts, instead of setting tags that need _constant_ updating ...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @CBroe . I have amended the code above that should bring the class through if -100 days have passed from the current date, but frustratingly this is not showing. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This now looks like it's working, think it was a caching issue! Posting answer in here now for future developers.

Answer (score 0):

This currently checks the post date, and if the post date is -100 to the current date. It will add a class onto it.

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    ?>
    Found <?php echo $query->found_posts; ?> Results<br />
    <div class='search-filter-results-list'>

        <?php
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

            // Get post published date
            $post_date = get_the_date('Ymd');
            $current_date = current_time('Ymd');
            $future_date = date('Ymd', strtotime('-100 days'));

            // post published date is -100 days before current date
            $class_to_add = ($post_date <= $current_date && $post_date >= $future_date) ? ' your-custom-class' : '';
            ?>

            <div class='search-filter-result-item<?php echo esc_attr($class_to_add); ?>'>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p><br /><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                    <p><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'small' ); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <p><?php the_category(); ?></p>
                <p><?php the_tags(); ?></p>
                <p><small><?php the_date(); ?></small></p>
                <hr />
            </div>

            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```